# Getting full (purpose, usage) Table names in SAP Hana

Tags: metadata, sap-hana

Each table in SAP Hana has a purpose, for example, `BSEG` is *Accounting Document Segment* and `BKPF` is *Accounting Document Header*.

Is there anything in Hana (along the lines of `Select * From Tables`) *or* a full list elsewhere on the Intertubes, that will get me the purpose\usage of each table in Hana?

I'm trying to put together a Workflow for [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) that'll allow me to look up the definitions and it would be nice if I can get it to tell me "Look Up BSEG (Accounting Document Segment)" as I'm searching inside the workflow.

I've already got the list of names, just really could do with that purpose\usage if possible!

Comment: This hasn't much to do with HANA, which happens to be the platform on which the SAP ERP system is running. Object names are in the ERP application domain.

Comment: So, is there an easily scrapable\downloadable list anywhere?

Comment: Who knows... In any case, when put like this, the question is unfortunately off-topic here, I'm afraid. You might have better luck on SAP support forums (if such exist). Don't expect this information to come officially from SAP though.

Comment: Feel free to make that the answer (if it's the answer, it's the answer) and I'll give you some points...